# Problems receiving POST variables from PHP

Tags: php, post, insomnia

I have a function developed by PHP that at the moment all I want it to do is to return the value of the variable $_POST['token']

I tried:

```
public function actionGetuserbytoken() {
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), TRUE);
 $id = $data['token'];
 return $id;
}
```

Or I also just tried:

```
public function actionGetuserbytoken() {
     return $_POST['token'];
 }
```

I tried doing the POST with Insomnia to check what is going on:
[image]

I feel this is a very absurd question but I can't understand why I can't get the value of the POST in either of the two ways.

Comment: So, $data returns an empty array?

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy yes

Answer (score 0):

The `php://input` stream can only be read once per request. Yii is likely reading the payload before you can, which means that the body is empty when you read the data.

Instead of using `php://input`, try the following:

```php
$data = json_decode(Yii::app()->request->getRawBody(), true);
```

Comment: I tried with Yii::$app>request->getRawBody() (I'm using Yii2) but still the same problem, it returns NULL